# Roots of intersecting two functions

Tags: graphing-functions

> $f(x) = k³x+ k³-2$ cuts the curve $g(x) = \ln(|x|)$ at exactly one point then $'k'$ may lie ...

My attempt : $f(x)=g(x)$ Then $\quad K^3=\frac{\ln(|x|)+2)}{(x+1)}$

Then plot the graph.

And by seeing the graph for $k^3=(1,\infty)$ you will get corresponding one value of $x$.
(Use the calculator to plot the graph)

But answer is $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt e},e\right)$, but here $0<\frac{1}{\sqrt e}<1$.

So, where did I make a mistake here?

Comment: What is in the case $$x=-1$$?

Comment: Please edit properly

Comment: $k$ must be a tangent line, so has $k$ with the curve exactly one point together

Comment: I think you must plot $g(x)$ in the range $-\infty < x < \infty, x\ne 0$ And $f(x)$ with several values of $k$. See how changing $k$ moves the cut point candidate.